# HTTP Error 500.30 - ASP.NET Core app failed to start - azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am running a blazor wasm hosted project 6.0 and in development it perfectly works, but when I deploy/publish it to azure app, i get the following error

```
HTTP Error 500.30 - ASP.NET Core app failed to start
Common solutions to this issue:
The app failed to start
The app started but then stopped
The app started but threw an exception during startup
Troubleshooting steps:
Check the system event log for error messages
Enable logging the application process' stdout messages
Attach a debugger to the application process and inspect
For more information visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=2028265
```

How will I debug the issue? It says system event log, The application is hosted in azure. is there any mechanism to know the exact cause of the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to see the logs and analyse the exact cause of error when hosted in azure I did the following:

```
https://<yoursitename>.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/dump
```

this will give you an errorlog folder and you can analyse the exact cause of error.

Comment: it shows the same error for me